# Android: Placing a text under a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to place a text under an image but the text is over lapping on the image.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/snap"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:paddingTop="32sp"
        android:drawablePadding="-22sp"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Please how do I place the text below the image. Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"` instead of  `android:background="@drawable/snap"` and get rid of  `android:paddingTop="32sp"` and  `android:drawablePadding="-22sp"`

the property `android:drawableTop` takes care of drawing the drawable above your text. E.g

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/shutterButton" 
    android:text="SNAP" />
```

Comment: Can I set the background transparent to remove the background button effect

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:paddingTop="32sp"
        android:drawablePadding="-22sp"
        android:text="SNAP"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use to accomplish this: 
note that i use PercentRelativeLayout.

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/Tesksten" <-- and of course the text.
    android:id="@+id/btContent"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu" <-- display icon on top
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="16%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

What it looks like:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I would put the Button and the Text field as seperate containers, and then place them both in a LinearLayout with vertical orientation:

`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/snap"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCamera" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="SNAP"
            android:id="@+id/textSnap"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: I would prefer drawableTop

Comment: Ah ok, why? What's the advantage or why would you prefer that?

Comment: Above code has 3 classes LinearLayout, Button, TextView to display as desired. And drawableTop will require only and only Button. So processing will be reduced and hence optimum usage of available resource

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about drawableTop, nice to learn something new here!